# How to set up a gateway node?

Tags: nodes, peers

I have two nodes running in my local machine. one public facing and another connected ONLY to the public facing node. I ensure they are whitelisted and in different ports. the nodes connect just fine, but for some reason my "hidden" node is not syncing. The data transmitted between it and the public facing one is just a few KBs. If i run both on regtest, generating blocks and sending txs happen basically instantly, so that works fine. Whats going on in mainnet that it doesnt allow it to sync? Is there something i need to configure?

Comment: You should post some detail about how they are configured, for example how have you connected them together, and what whitelist configuration was used. Using `getblockchaininfo` on the non-listening node should give some more information about its state (ie, has it synchronised any headers).

Comment: [blockchaininfo](http://i66.tinypic.com/2ryhea8.png) is what i have. 

The listening node is set up with -port=5801 -listen -debug -whitelist=127.0.0.1
and the hidden node is set up with -port=5802 -connect=127.0.0.1:5801 -debug

Comment: Huh, interesting. In general you might be better off looking at `whitebind` for this application, but I'm not sure why you're running into trouble here. Can you verify that `5801` is listening, for example with `netstat` or `telnet`?

Comment: yep. i used netstat and it says ESTABLISHED. In regtest it works just fine. I'll try whitebind and see how it goes.